# auto generate Graphql's mutations and queries for using in uiplayground instead of typing them by hand

Tags: .net-core, graphql

i need a tools that generates my mutations and queries from .net core Apis instead of typing theme with my hand in uiplayground!
is there any tools for it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and found the **Apollo Studio**. It can do the same what I needed.